# Build app for ios (react-native)

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, react-native, mobile-development

I used command: 'react-native run-ios' and I have a message "Build Succeeded", but when I can find app to install on my iphone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different things here.

Running `react-native run-ios` will run your application on your simulator.

To run it in your device, you'll need to run the application from xCode. You can check RN's official docs on running on device [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html#content).